# Можно ли напоить что-л. ароматом и "стелиться отовсюду"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Альпини – путешественник, натуралист-ботаник, врач и по
>   совместительству человек, который привез в Италию кофе. Вот прямо
>   сюда, в этот дом. И навсегда **напоил город терпким ароматом**,
>   который **стелется** теперь по площади **отовсюду** – из
>   многочисленных уютных кофеен, из каждого офиса и жилого окошка.

"Напоил", я думаю, авторская находка, он за неё бороться будет, а что со "стелется"? просто *повсюду*? Или глагол надо менять? *Сочится, просачивается...*

Comment: Напоил ароматом - вполне корректно. В словарях это значение есть. 3. обычно страд. прич. прош.: напоённый. что чем. Трад.-поэт. Наполнить, насытить чем-л. Воздух напоён ароматом цветов.

Comment: И стелится - тоже корректно. Из словаря: Распространяться, простираться по поверхности или низко над поверхностью чего-либо.  ***Над изрытой землей стлался удушливый запах гари. Поповкин, Семья Рубанюк.***

Comment: У меня ж ещё смутительное ***стелется отовсюду***...

Comment: Вас смущает слово "отовсюду"?

Comment: Нет, конечно! Взаимоотношение слов *стелется отовсюду*.

Comment: Ну все верно: отовсюду. потому что дальше указываются места, с которых этот аромат исходит. Если написать "повсюдю', изменится смысл. Придется написать: стелится повсюду: в кафе, в офисах. А здесь имеется в виду: арамат струится из кафе, офисов и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если *напоил* "навсегда", то в лучшем случае (если не вспоминать Моцарта, который всего лишь "надолго") напившимся больше не хочется. Может, *наполнил*? *Стелиться* может *видимая* сущность, причём ниже уровня абонятельных рецепторов. Аромат же, скорее, *струится к площади отовсюду*.

Answer (score 0):

Я в предложенном фрагменте заменила бы только "стелется" на "доносится" (до площади).)))